# What is a good way in object oriented programing to create lists and filter various results?

Tags: python, oop

I have a method which creates a list of files of a directory, but i have multiple other methods which do the same plus some additional filtering during the loop.

This looks like a very bad solution to me, i'm very interested in how to do this more elegant.

Here is a simple example of what i'm doing:

```
class foo(object):

    def read_files_in_dir(...)
        ....

    def filter_x(...):
        for file in read_files_in_dir(...):
            if file.startswith("x"):
                yield file

    def filter_y(....):
        for file in read_files_in_dir(...):
            if file.startswith("y"):
                yield file

    ...
```

I don't want to merge all the results of the `filter`-functions, every result has a different meaning since i'm reading different directories which require different ways of filtering.

Is there any way to have a central function for the loop and the possibility of different filtering options without parametrizing the hell out of it?

// EDIT

I'm doing it the following way now:

```
class Something(object):

    @staticmethod
    def read_files_in_dir(self, directory, filter_func=lambda _: return True):
        for file in directory:
            if filter_func(file):
                yield file

    class Filters(object):

        @staticmethod
        def filter1(file):
            return True if *some_condition* else False
```

I run something like this then:

```
filtered = Something.read_files_in_dir(*directory*, Something.Filters.filter1)
```

Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Just refactor and add a parameter. You don't need any fancy OOP design patterns for this kind of thing.

Comment: Hm, but i have lots of filters, so putting them all in one method would cause an if-statement chaos i think :-/

Comment: Make filters a separate class and pass one or more instances of it as arguments to something else which uses them to the filter the files in a directory.

Comment: @jervis, so you can have a composite filter. `myFilter = lambda x: all(predicate(x) for predicate in [f1, f2, f3, f4])`

Answer (score 2):

Your example may be over-simplified, but the following should do pretty much what yours does:

```
def read_files_in_dir(...)
   ...

def filter(self, param, ...):
    return (file for file in read_files_in_dir(...) if file.startswith(param))
```

If your filter is more complex than what fits in a single test, you can create additional methods/functions that you can pass the file instance to and return True/False depending on whatever criteria you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
predicates = [
  lambda x: x % 3 == 0,
  lambda x: x % 5 == 0
]

items = range(0, 100)

filtered = [
  item for item in items if
    all(predicate(item) for predicate in predicates)
  ]

print(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

When building a filtering system, the general idea is often to create some **universe** of data and then to run each item in that universe through a bunch of **filtering functions**, each of which takes an item and returns a boolean result. Items from the universe are retained only if all filters return true.

Here's a simple example, in a functional style. It's easy enough to convert to an object-oriented approach if the larger program requires it:

```
def main():
    universe = read_files_in_dir()
    filters = [is_odd, larger_than_ten]

    for item in universe:
        if all(f(item) for f in filters):
            print item

def read_files_in_dir():
    return list(range(20))

def is_odd(item):
    return bool(item % 2)

def larger_than_ten(item):
    return item > 10

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dologan answer is good. 
The idea is to pass the filter value as a parameter to the filter function. 
However to the To make the filter more robust I would use a filter dictionary. 
In the dictionary you can specify the type of search and the value: 
For example:
filterList = {'start':'y',.....)

If you want to be more sophisticated  you can put the filter function in a list and pass the string as a param.
For example:

```
filename = 'try_me.py'
filterString = 't'
filterListA = [str.startswith]
filterListB = [str.endswith, str.startswith]
filterListC = [str.find]

def my filter(filterList, filterString):
       for filterFunc in filterList:
          print filterFunc(filename,filterString)
```